# NGINX and nodeJs works with http but not https

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, https

I have this config for NGINX:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  rahim27.fr;

  ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/rahim27.fr/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/rahim27.fr/privkey.pem;

  error_log logs/error.log warn;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

And this basic NodeJS server :

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8080);
```

When I go to http://rahim27.fr/, I get my `hello world` but if I try https://rahim27.fr/ I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, with curl it gives me `curl: (7) Failed to connect to rahim27.fr port 443: No route to host` from Linux (the VM) and `curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed` from Windows.

The server is in a cloud VM, I opened up all ports in the cloud dashboard and in the VM itself.

The SSL certificate was generated by certbot automatically.

**What I want :**

1. Have https://rahim27.fr/ return a `hello world`
2. After serving both http and https correctly, I would also like to redirect all http traffic to https

**What I tried :**

1. Looking on stackoverflow
2. Opening up all ports on the VM (at least while I'm on the development phase)

Comment: You can try remove proxy_http_version,proxy_set_header,proxy_cache_bypass directive.   Then restart nginx

Comment: @Freax I just did, nothing changed, same problem

Comment: @AbderrahimBenmelouka were you able to resolve this? Have the same issue here.

Comment: Sadly, I wasn't and I ended up giving up on it :/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to remove the ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key lines and use certbot which takes care of automatically managing the https.

I invite you to follow the following easy-to-follow instructions:

https://certbot.eff.org